# How do I get the max values of tuples that are next to each other in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

Say I have the following tuples.

```
dummy = [("text", 10), ("This is the Sentence", 20), 
         ("that I Want", 20), ("to Get", 20), 
         ("text", 8), ("text", 6)]
```

I want to get that "`This is the Sentence that I Want to Get`" and ignore the rest. The text in particular always have the largest value (in this case it's 20) and they're next to each other. Basically, it will only collect the tuples with max values that are next to each other.

With the following code I only collect the first max tuple, but it ignores the rest.

```
from operator import itemgetter

max(dummy, key=itemgetter(1))
```

How do I make it that it will get all other max values?

Comment: What if there are tuples with the max value but they're not next to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not:
get the max key using dict values and implement filter by it

```
m_value = max(dict(dummy).values())
" ".join([x for x, n in dummy if n == m_value])
```

my result is:

```
'This is the Sentence that I Want to Get'
```

Comment: It's not working, I think the first line is supposed to be `m_value = max(dict(dummy).values())`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
>>> t = np.array([d[0] for d in dummy])
>>> v = np.array([d[1] for d in dummy])
>>> print(t[v==v.max()])

['This is the Sentence' 'that I Want' 'to Get']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

```
from operator import itemgetter

dummy = [("text", 10), ("This is the Sentence", 20), 
         ("that I Want", 20), ("to Get", 20), 
         ("text", 8), ("text", 6)]

max_num = max(dummy, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
text_blocks = [text for text, num in dummy if num == max_num]

sentence = ' '.join(text_blocks)

print(sentence)

# This is the Sentence that I Want to Get
```

You could improve the code further by using [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) as your dummy's items

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
from operator import itemgetter
# find the max value
max_sen, max_val = max(dummy, key=itemgetter(1))
# filter based on max value and join
" ". join([x[0] for x in filter(lambda x:x[1]==max_val, dummy)])
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial assumption seems to be wrong. Don't consider the implementations mentioned in this answers. Leaving this here for informational purpose.

> Most answers here use `sort` or `max` or similar ways which results in
> iterating through the data twice. Which is unnecessary I believe.
> Check the below implementation you should get your desired output with
> a single iteration through data.

And the answers I have added seems to be performing worse. Especially the `answer 2` using string. I believe culprit might be reassigning the string every time.

Also the list comprehension seems to be performing far better than appending. Making the answer 1 also comparatively slower to some other answers.

To verify these you may try this code snippet https://gist.github.com/RitwikGopi/1b36a900219e7c087c95baa99fdf65e2#file-test-py

answer 1:

```
dummy = [("text", 10), ("This is the Sentence", 20),
         ("that I Want", 20), ("to Get", 20),
         ("text", 8), ("text", 6)]

max_val = float("-inf")
max_data = []

for data, value in dummy:
    if value > max_val:
        max_val = value
        max_data = [data]
    elif value == max_val:
        max_data.append(data)
    else:
        continue

print(max_data)
```

answer 2:

```
dummy = [("text", 10), ("This is the Sentence", 20),
         ("that I Want", 20), ("to Get", 20),
         ("text", 8), ("text", 6)]

max_val = float("-inf")
max_data = ""

for data, value in dummy:
    if value > max_val:
        max_val = value
        max_data = data
    elif value == max_val:
        max_data += " " + data
    else:
        continue

print(max_data)
```

Comment: from my side of view: over code (like not python way) and looks like it will have bad performance

Comment: Agree it might not be the most pythonic way of writing solution. But got a question. Why do you believe this will perform badly?

Comment: try to find in the web python loop+append vs list comprehension

Comment: @BrownBear how about now will it be better?

Comment: not sure and looks like you have an error now

Comment: Yeah for got to make one change.

Comment: may be in performance your current solution is better, but still it is difficult to read

Comment: @BrownBear actually my performance with string is even worse. Readability I don't know for some one not coming from python background I feel my code might be readable. Just because it is implemented using simple logic. List comprehension and some other inbuilt python functionalities might not be familiar to beginner. But you are correct in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a Pandas one-liner? With a walrus operator as a bonus

```
import pandas as pd

' '.join((df :=pd.DataFrame(dummy)).loc[df[1] == max(df[1]),0])
```

output

```
'This is the Sentence that I Want to Get'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[i for i, j in dict(dummy).items() if j==max(dict(dummy).values())]
```

This would give the max values

example result =

```
['This is the Sentence', 'that I Want', 'to Get']
```

Comment: This will not guarantee the order of the sentence

Comment: Why are you using `dict(dummy).items()`??? And don't calculate this every time in the loop: `max(dict(dummy).values())`, that makes this algorithm unnecessarily quadratic time